# OCI Statements and bind variables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface

We have an issue with a C program inserting values using OCI into the oracle database 
The table structure is: 
desc table employee;

```
 Name                       Null?     Type

 EMPLOYEE_ID                          NUMBER
 SALARY                               NUMBER
 DEPARTMENT_ID                        NUMBER
```

The query we use on the table is:

```
Insert into employee(employee_ID, salary, department_id) values ( :1, DECODE(:2,  4294967295, -1, :2), :3);
```

What we intended to do in the insert statement with the decode is that `if the value of "salary" (:2) is equal to 4294967295` then `insert the value -1 into the database otherwise insert the original value (:2)`

 In the C program, three values were bound to the query.

On execution of the query we get the following error message:

> Error - OCI_ERROR ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Can the same bind variable be used twice in an OCI statement call with a DECODE? Is there a way we could modify the query and still achieve the translation of the value of salary?

Comment: Can you use triggers to check the data when it's inserted?
Can you do the check in c before the insert?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the same bind value number more than once in a query? i.e. (:2)? just use different numbers and change the bind statements accordingly. Oracle doesn't know the meaning of where the variables are used, it just matches up the numbers on the bind statement with the corresponding number in the prepared query.

Comment: I'm not sure about OCI in C, but in PHP + OCI, it's allowed to use the same placeholder multiple times (and bind only once). But anyway, I think Ryan's suggestion is worth to try: use multiple placeholder and bind multiple times.

Comment: FWIW, we had issues in the past with Oracle when using the same bind variable twice (although in a completely different context). I agree with @RyanVincent - use different numbers, change the bind statements, and check if it works.

Comment: It might also be a simple error in the C program (e.g. passing the wrong index to OCIBindByPos()) - could you please post the relevant C code, as well?

Answer (score 1):

Change your sql statement to:

```
Insert into employee(employee_ID, salary, department_id) values ( :1, DECODE(:2,  4294967295, -1, :3), :4);
```

and pass bind variables in following order

```
employee_ID, salary, salary, department_id
```

Note that salary needs to be passed twice for your requirement

Comment: To be more specific, OCI is misleading here, in that you can put any number after the colon, and as long as you bind in the sequential order of the bind placeholders, it still works. Not intuitive, I know...

Comment: That's absolutely correct, numbering just makes code to look easier and at the end you know how many variables you need to bind. Moreover, you can use characters and string(without spaces) as well.

Comment: Of course, the corollary of this is that cannot reuse the same bind as OP tried, you must bind the same C/C++ variable several times if you want to use it in several placeholders. Naming the placeholders the same doesn't help, as OP found out.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

```
Insert into employee(employee_ID, salary, department_id) values ( :employee_ID, DECODE(:salary,  4294967295, -1, :salary), :department_id);
```

And use:

[OCIBindByName()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci15r29.htm)

Then bind only

```
employee_ID, salary, department_id (order wouldn't matter anymore)
```

All the placeholders with same name are bound to single bind variable (space and performance efficient)

Answer (score 0):

Fast and dirty.

Write your C code mimicking what you expect OCI to do:

```
class OracleQuery{
public:
  OracleQuery(std::string aQuery) : query_(aQuery){}
  size_t setString(size_t aPlaceHolder, const std::string& aSubS);
  std::string getSQL(){ return query_; }
private:
  std::string query_;
};

size_t OracleQuery::setString(size_t aPlaceHolder, const std::string& aSubS)
{
  std::string toReplace = "'" + aSubS + "'";
  size_t countReplace = 0;
  std::string myPlaceHolder = ":" + std::to_string(aPlaceHolder);
  size_t len = myPlaceHolder.size();
  std::string myNewQuery;
  size_t pos = 0;
  while (true){
    pos = query_.find(myPlaceHolder, pos);
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
      break;
    ++countReplace;
    query_.replace(pos, len, toReplace);
  }
  return countReplace;
}
```

when you need it you can extend it with a setInt() method. And so on and so forth...